# Website 504 error when enabling UFW after upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 22.04, nginx, ufw

After upgrading the server from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04, enabling UFW made a website 504 error.

When enabling UFW the error is:

```
ERROR: problem running ufw-init
iptables-restore: line 4 failed
```

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 22.04, `ufw` can't be enabled when `iptables-persistent` or `netfilter-persistent` is installed.

This may be why you are seeing this:

```
WARN: detected other firewall applications:
netfilter-persistent, iptables-persistent
```

If you want to use `ufw`, you should:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge iptables-persistent  netfilter-persistent
```